# Can't add Library in eclipse android project ADT

Tags: java, android, eclipse, adt, google-play-services

EDIT: ANSWERED in comments

I have opened pandora's box worth of errors over the past few days and have boiled the source of my troubles down to my inability to correctly add the Google Play Services library into my project so I can have adMob ads. I should be able to go to Project>Properties>Android and then under Library hit add. However when I hit add, It's menu is all grayed out and I cant add, browse or do anything. I am using the new ADT bundle as of about April 2, "Build: v22.6.2-1085508". What exactly is wrong and how can I fix it?

Thank you very much!
Any help is greatly Appreciated!!

Comment: Have you imported the Play Services SDK library project into your Eclipse workspace?

Comment: Finnaly figured out what I was doing wrong. I needed to set it the google library into library mode in the android settings and then since eclipse knew there was at least one library available , it let me add it. Thanks for the response though! I appreciate it!